# Get sans font in pgfplots tick scale labels

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, fontspec

I use the fontspec package and the objective is to have a consistent font in the pgfplots diagrams. Sometimes, I have tick scale labels due to the magnitude of the respective axis. Changing the font setting in the "x tick scale label style" parameter does not seem to give the desired sans font (see the MWE and the corresponding figure).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Tex Gyre Heros}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    yticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    label style={font={\sffamily}},
    x tick scale label style={font={\sffamily}},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [
                xlabel={my x axis},
                ylabel={my y axis}
            ]
            \addplot [domain=1e-9:100e-9, samples=20, thick] {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX on overleaf but I had to use another font (GFS Artemisia) because your font is not available there. The output was the expected one.

Comment: Thank you for checking this. I have only access to a local instance of Overleaf/Sharelatex. Using the alternative fonts Fira sans or Noto sans, I can reproduce the problem. The tick scale labels are not written in a sans font.

Comment: You are right ... Didn't noticed that numbers

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly no expert in LaTeX font selection / management. However, it can be found in the unicode-math package documentation (chapter 4.1) that defined ranges of glyphs (the upright digit glyphs in this case) can be delegated to other fonts. If a main math font like Fira Math is selected, the upright glyphs can be delegated to another font (Tex Gyre Heros here). This produces the desired result.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Heros}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Heros}[range={up}]


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [
                xlabel={my x axis},
                ylabel={my y axis}
            ]
            \addplot [domain=1e-9:1e-7, samples=20, thick] {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]